# How Can I remove this error "socket: read check timed out(30) sock.c:240: Connection timed out"

Tags: load-testing, siege

I am working on siege 4.0.2 on ubuntu 16.04 environment. I need get a failed transaction when I simulate more than 1100 user, I know that if failed transaction comes means so there is a problem in server memory may be maemory out of failure.  How to understand the failed transaction ? And how to solve the problem for failed transaction comes ?

```
siege -c1190 -t1m  http://192.168.1.11:8080/


HTTP/1.1 200     7.02 secs:      57 bytes ==> GET  /kiosk/start
HTTP/1.1 200     7.01 secs:      57 bytes ==> GET  /kiosk/start
siege aborted due to excessive socket failure; you
can change the failure threshold in $HOME/.siegerc

Transactions:               3263 hits
Availability:              76.11 %
Elapsed time:               9.34 secs
Data transferred:           0.18 MB
Response time:              1.98 secs
Transaction rate:         349.36 trans/sec
Throughput:             0.02 MB/sec
Concurrency:              691.94
Successful transactions:        3263
Failed transactions:            1024
Longest transaction:            7.75
Shortest transaction:           0.03
```

When I simulate 1100 users , I got a `error discriptor tables full sock. c 119: Too many open files` and then I do `ulimit - n 10000` and the error went.
Then I again simulate 1100 users, I got a new error

```
[error] socket: read error Connection reset by peer sock.c:539: Connection reset by peer
```

Could not able to throw the error . How to remove this error ? Anybody please help me